# Spreadsheet running slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with about 12 buttons.
When each button is clicked the associated script makes the relevant sheet visible.

Everything works but recently I have found that where it use to take about a second to run the script its now running 6-7 seconds.

It doesn't happen everytime I use the spreadsheet, but when it does it can last for several hours.

It sometimes works well through the day but in the evening this issue happens.

And today it has happened in the afternoon, where it has been fine all morning.

Is there anywhere or anyhow I can check what is going on please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem? Until then, it's all guesswork, I'm afraid.

Comment: You can look in the execution transcript and you could also use stack driver logging.  If you just talking about Javascript then brush up on Dev Tools.

Comment: Thanks Cooper - Not heard of Stack driver logging - Just googled it - is it a paid service? I also looked at 'my executions' but not much clues there.....most times the scripts take 0.xx seconds to complete, but then on different days and at different times the same scripts takes upto 60 seconds to complete......over the past week there has only been one failed script........so i suspect code is fine, but something else is slowing down the script at certain times